# Ceiling Fan - Single Switch, but Dual Switch installation

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

I have a two switch plate & installed a ceiling fan using dual switch instruction (white/white, black/ungrounded, blue/ungrounded).  Fan & light work fine from one switch, but I learned second switch is for a wall outlet, not the ceiling. Do I have to rewire it for single switch (white/white, black & blue to black ungrounded) or is it fine?

Comment: neither the preexisting wiring or your setup is clear. Could you expand on what was the wiring and what is now the wiring? For example, does the distant outlet receive its neutral through the switch box? And What country are you in?

Comment: Does the fan and light work?  Does the other switch still control the outlet?

Comment: This will require a photo.  And some work on the description.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense:

"Fan & light work fine from one switch...... Do I have to rewire it for single switch "

Do you mean they work fine from there respective switch? If so then your OK to leave it as is. Just remember that the outlet is also controlled when the fan (or light) is on.

Comment: If you don't have enough information to understand the question, it's best to hold off of an answer until the OP follows up. I also wouldn't say it's OK if it's working fine, since there could be dangerous situations created by incorrect wiring that will still work fine (e.g. bad ground, hot ground, switched neutral). "You're likely ok", "it's ok to do X", but avoid saying "the wiring you've done is ok."

Comment: Directions from Fan: For a single switch: black from ceiling to black & blue from fan, white to white. Dual Switch: White to white, black to black, second ungrounded wire from ceiling to blue wire from fan. I followed the Dual Switch instructions, but only have a single switch. Fan works fine, turn switch on and use pulls for blades & light. My question is if I can leave it like this or I need to rewire it for a single switch. There are two switches on the wall and I assumed that was a 'dual' switch, when in fact, one is for the ceiling and one is for a wall outlet for a lamp.

Comment: You say that the light and fan turn on when a single switch is turned on (with the help of the pull chains). This is a typical installation for a single switch configuration. When both the fan and light are on, does either turn off when the second switch on the wall is turned on and off?

Comment: Or with the wall switch off, does either the fan or the light come on when the pull chains are used?